# slider revolution refreshes page no matter where you click

Tags: slider, click, refresh, revolution-slider

My slider : https://cosmosdesign.be/web-design/
when i click on the spaceman or text, the page just refreshes. i went trough all the options but there is nothing that worked , anyone else had the same problem?
the page should not refresh when you click on the spaceman or text.
EDIT: I found the problem, the text in my page section on wordpress was linked to the same place so everywhere i clicked it went to that page.
My gf wanted you to know she found this problem, i am ashamed

Comment: you could add the options you tried and failed as well for better clarification .

Comment: I almost tried everything. I thought the problem was in "actions"
but when i checked i could not find anything there. I also created an action for "portfolio" when you click on it you should be redirected to the portfolio but instead it just refreshes the page